# How to enable clipboard and drag-and-drop while using Ubuntu 20.10 as guest for VirtualBox 6.0.24 running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS host?

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, virtualization, clipboard, 20.10

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS with VirtualBox 6.0.24:

```
$ apt-cache policy virtualbox-6.0 
virtualbox-6.0:
  Installed: 6.0.24-139119~Ubuntu~xenial
  Candidate: 6.0.24-139119~Ubuntu~xenial
  Version table:
 *** 6.0.24-139119~Ubuntu~xenial 500
        500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial/contrib amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I have installed Ubuntu 20.10 inside the VirtualBox, and enabled bidirectional clipboard and drag-and-drop for this VM.

Inside the VM I have installed all possible VirtualBox guest packages from [*multiverse*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/groovy/virtualbox) - `virtualbox-guest-dkms`, `virtualbox-guest-utils` and `virtualbox-guest-x11`:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep virtualbox
ii  virtualbox-guest-dkms                    6.1.14-dfsg-4                       all          x86 virtualization solution - guest addition module source for dkms
ii  virtualbox-guest-utils                   6.1.14-dfsg-4                       amd64        x86 virtualization solution - non-X11 guest utilities
ii  virtualbox-guest-x11                     6.1.14-dfsg-4                       amd64        x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities

$ ps x | grep -i vbox | grep -v grep
   1415 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --seamless
   1416 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --seamless
   1422 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --draganddrop
   1423 ?        Sl     0:05 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --draganddrop
   1427 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --vmsvga
   1428 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --vmsvga
```

Manual run of `VBoxClient --clipboard` does not help, this application exits with 0 exit-code and do not want to run in background.

But in the foreground it fails as shown below:

```
$ VBoxClient --clipboard -f
Shared Clipboard: Starting X11 event thread
Shared Clipboard: Stopping X11 event thread ...
Shared Clipboard: X11 event thread terminated successfully
Error connecting to host service, rc=VERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED
Service terminated abnormally with VERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED
Running service failed: VERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED
```

So the clipboard and drag-and-drop are not working.
Screen resolution adjust and seamless mode works as expected in the same time.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Note: installation of GA 6.0.24 ISO instead helps, but I want to use deb-packages with DKMS to avoid reinstallation of GA on each kernel update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by incompatibility between installed virtualbox host 6.0.24 and virtualbox guest additions 6.1.14.

The solution is to install latest `virtualbox-6.1` package on the host. And then deb-version of Guest Additions will work as expected and fully-functional including clipboard and drag-and-drop.